# Java Swing Threading with Updatable JProgressBar

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, swingworker

First off I've been working with Java's Concurrency package quite a bit lately but I have found an issue that I am stuck on. I want to have and Application and the Application can have a `SplashScreen` with a status bar and the loading of other data. So I decided to use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( call the splash component here )`. The `SplashScreen` then appears with a `JProgressBar` and runs a group of threads. But I can't seem to get a good handle on things. I've looked over `SwingWorker` and tried using it for this purpose but the thread just returns. Here is a bit of pseudo code. and the points I'm trying to achieve.

- Have an Application that has a `SplashScreen` that pauses while loading info
- Be able to run multiple threads under the `SplashScreen`
- Have the progress bar of the `SplashScreen` Update-able yet not exit until all threads are done.

Launching splash screen

```
try {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( SplashScreen );
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) { }
```

Splash screen construction

```
SplashScreen extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    public void run() {
        //run threads
        //while updating status bar
    }
}
```

I have tried many things including `SwingWorkers`, Threads using CountDownLatch's, and others. The CountDownLatch's actually worked in the manner I wanted to do the processing but I was unable to update the GUI. When using the `SwingWorkers` either the `invokeAndWait` was basically nullified (which is their purpose) or it wouldn't update the GUI still even when using a `PropertyChangedListener`. If someone else has a couple ideas it would be great to hear them. Thanks in advance.

I actually got ready to post better code to help out and found my solution. I thank you for all who helped.

Comment: Your problem may get solved more quickly and correctly if you could create and post an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org).

Comment: Sorry, I was heading to bed as I posted and all I had was pretty ugly code to post so I was hoping to get the idea across, if the below answer doesn't work for me I'll post some real code. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to call the frame inside invokeAndWait but you should update progress bar state like this.

```
try {
   SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
//update state of the progress bar here
     }
   });
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
 } catch (InvocationTargetException e) { }
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with threads or the SwingWorkers, I'm updating my question with some better code. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 5):

For running a series of operations in the background and reporting progress, use [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

The `background` method does the background processing.
Use the `publish` method to post periodic status updates.
Override the `process` method to handle the updates (`process` always executes on the EDT).

```
progressBar = new JProgressBar();
sw = new SwingWorker<Boolean,Integer>() {
    protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // If any of the operations fail, return false to notify done() 
        // Do thing 1
        publish(25);  // 25% done
        // Do thing 2
        publish(50);  // 50% done
        // Do thing 3
        publish(75);  // 75% done
        // Do thing 4
        return true;
    }
    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
        for (Integer i : chunks)
            progressBar.setValue(i);
    }
    protected void done() {
        try {
            boolean b = get();
            if (b)
                progressBar.setValue(100); // 100% done
            else
                // Notify the user processing failed
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // Notify the user processing was interrupted
        }
        catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                // Notify the user processing raised an exception
        }
    }
};
```

**Addendum:**

This can be extended to multiple tasks, it just requires changing how you approach setting the progress bar. Here's what comes to mind:

Have an array of completion counter, one per task.

```
int[] completions = new int[numTasks];
Arrays.fill(completions,0);
```

Start the SwingWorkers, each passed an index number. The `process` or `done` methods then call something like this to update the overall progress bar.

```
void update(int index, int percComplete) {
    completions[index] = percComplete;
    int total = 0;
    for(int comp: completions)
        total += comp/numTasks;
    overallPB.setValue(total);
}
```

Optionally, display a JProgressBar per task.

**Addendum 2:**

If the tasks vary in completion time (eg, cache hit vs cache miss), you may want to investigate [ProgressMonitor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html). It's a progress dialog that only appears if the task takes more than some (configurable, default 500ms) amount of time.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work I need multiple swing workers and they still continue while the execution of the next code continues, which is why I had mentioned the invokeAndWait() method, because I need it to wait and I'll need multiple SwingWorkers running and I don't want to continue until all the workers have completed.