# Progress Bar Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jprogressbar, tablecelleditor

I am using JProgressBar to show progress. But, How to show the progressBar as loading from 0 to 100? I got the code from internet and its working except the progressBar is not loading.

code

```
progressFrame = new JFrame(); // frame to display progress bar
progressBar = new JProgressBar(0,100);
progressBar.setValue(0);
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
progressFrame.add(progressBar);

new SwingWorker<Void,Void>()
    {
        protected Void doInBackground() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            progressBar.setValue(0);
            frame.setEnabled(false); // frame = main frame

            //tableclass creates a JTable with data from database
            tableclass = new TheDatabaseTable(deptName);//it takes time to create
            progressBar.setValue(50);
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.setContentPane(tableclass);

            frame.validate();
            frame.repaint();

            progressBar.setValue(100);
            //progressFrame.dispose();
            return null;
        }; 
        protected void done()
        {
            //progressFrame.setVisible(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            progressFrame.dispose();
            frame.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }.execute();
```

I would appreciate if anyone edit the above code to work. Thank you.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5171758/1427942). Overwrite `process` and set the value of the progress bar inside this method. To update it call `publish` inside your `doInBackground` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use threads for that. Design a class that implements `Runnable` interface which will update the values like this.

```
class ProgressBarUpdator implements java.lang.Runnable {

    /**
     * Progress bar that shows the current status
     */
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jpb = null;
    /**
     * Progress bar value
     */
    private java.lang.Integer value = null;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param jpb The progress bar this has to update
     */
    public ProgressBarUpdator(javax.swing.JProgressBar jpb) {
        this.jpb = jpb;
        jpb.setMaximum(100);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value to the progress bar
     * @param value Value to set
     */
    public void setValue(java.lang.Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Action of the thread will be executed here. The value of the progress bar will be set here.
     */
    public void run() {
        do {
            if (value != null) {
                jpb.setValue((int)java.lang.Math.round(java.lang.Math.floor(value.intValue() * 100 / maximum)));
            }
            try {
                java.lang.Thread.sleep(100L);
            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (value == null || value.intValue() < jpb.getMaximum());
    }
}
```

and in your frame class use `progressBar` with the new class like this

```
ProgressBarUpdator ju = new ProgressBarUpdator(progressBar);
new java.lang.Thread(ju).start();
```

Whenever you want to change the value just use the statement

```
ju.setValue([Value to set]);
```

Comment: Could you please let me know what to initialize for maximum =? in run() method, Thank you.

Comment: That is the progress bar maximum. you can set it to 100 like `jpb.setMaximum(100);`. This is already available in constructor. Check once.

Comment: -1 NEVER, EVER create/update ANY Swing component from out side the Event Dispatching Thread. Swing uses a single thread model. See [Concucurrneyc in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). This was one of the problems with the original question

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay. will look into that approach too. I do write my programs like this and they work smoothly.

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli The problem extends from the fact that Swing is NOT thread safe (there's no synchronisation). Because you don't control the paint process, it's possible that as you are updating the model, the repaint manager will attempt a repaint, meaning you could end up with dirty paints. The application I inherited 3 years had lots of code done this way, over that 3 year period, we've been able to remove 90% of the "strange" and "unexplained" and "difficult to replicate" problems by ensuring that all UI updates are executed within the EDT

Answer (score 12):

Gotta love code from the internet...oh...

The code you have violates the singe thread rules of Swing and thus, is a bad example.

You have a number of options with `SwingWorker`.  You could `publish` the progress and use the `process` method to update the progress bar or you could use a `PropertyChangeListener` and monitor progress change events created by calling the `setProgress` method of the `SwingWorker`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SwingWorkerProgress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingWorkerProgress();
    }

    public SwingWorkerProgress() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JProgressBar pbProgress;
        private JButton start;

        public TestPane() {

            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            pbProgress = new JProgressBar();
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(pbProgress, gbc);

            start = new JButton("Start");
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(start, gbc);

            start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    start.setEnabled(false);
                    ProgressWorker pw = new ProgressWorker();
                    pw.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                            String name = evt.getPropertyName();
                            if (name.equals("progress")) {
                                int progress = (int) evt.getNewValue();
                                pbProgress.setValue(progress);
                                repaint();
                            } else if (name.equals("state")) {
                                SwingWorker.StateValue state = (SwingWorker.StateValue) evt.getNewValue();
                                switch (state) {
                                    case DONE:
                                        start.setEnabled(true);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    });
                    pw.execute();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public class ProgressWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            int i = 0;
            int max = 2000;

            while (i < max) {
                i += 10;
                int progress = Math.round(((float)i / (float)max) * 100f);
                setProgress(progress);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(25);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid inconvertible type exception between object and int, replace, line, "int progress = (int) evt.getNewValue();"
with "int progress = ((Integer) evt.getNewValue()).intValue();"

Comment: @AVA Why? It's autoboxed

Comment: Sorry, May please be ignored! I got exception in version 1.6.0_16.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class ProgressBar {
    /**
     * JProgressBar
     * 
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("New Window");
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //JLabel textLoad = new JLabel();
        //textLoad.setText("Loading ....");

        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();        
        progressBar.setMinimum(0);
        progressBar.setMaximum(100);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        frame.add(progressBar);                               

        for (int i = progressBar.getMinimum(); i <= progressBar.getMaximum(); i++) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            progressBar.setValue(i);
        }

        textLoad.setText("Done !");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide some coment to your answer, not just the code.

Answer (score -3):

```
/*
By
Dr. Amit Kumar Kapoor
Assistant Professor, Maharaja Agrasen Institute of Management & Technology, Jagadhri
E-mail ID: akbrightfuture@gmail.com
*/
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    class progressbardemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
       {
          JProgressBar pb;
          JButton b1;
              progressbardemo()
              {
                 super("Progressbar");
                 setLayout(null);
                 b1=new JButton("Click");
                 b1.setBackground(Color.yellow);             
                 pb=new JProgressBar(1,100);
                 pb.setValue(0);
                 pb.setStringPainted(true);
                 pb.setForeground(Color.red);   
                 pb.setBackground(Color.white); 
                 b1.setBounds(20,20,80,25);pb.setBounds(110,20,200,25);
                 pb.setVisible(false);
                 add(b1);
                 add(pb);             
                 b1.addActionListener(this);
                 setResizable(false);
                 setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              }
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
               {
                  int i=0;
                  if(e.getSource()==b1)
                     {
                       pb.setVisible(true);
                    try
                    {
                       while(i<=100)
                       {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
        pb.paintImmediately(0, 0, 200, 25);
            pb.setValue(i);
                         i++;
        }
                     }
                     catch(Exception e1)
                     {
        System.out.print("Caughted exception is ="+e1);
                     }
                    }
               }
              public static void main(String arg[])
              {
              progressbardemo m=new progressbardemo();
              m.setSize(330,100);
              m.setVisible(true);
              Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
              int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - m.getWidth()) / 2);
              int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - m.getHeight()) / 2);
              m.setLocation(x, y); 
              }
       }
```

Comment: please stop spreading your sub-optimal code all over the site, already pointed out the issues that need fixing in your previous answer ;-) Anyway, even if fixed, it's discouraged to post the exact same answer repeatedly: chances are that the copies either don't really fit the question or the questions are duplicates (which should be flagged as such)