# Java Swing ProgressBar update while computing

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, jprogressbar, swingutilities

There are some example for similar question 
([Progress Bar Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199091/progress-bar-java/15199220#15199220)) and ([Java uploading percentage progressbar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219538/java-uploading-percentage-progressbar-thread)) but didn't understand how to make it work for my code.

My main has 2 panels one over the other (one of which is a tabbedPane with 2 tabs)

```
public class MainIRH {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 20));
                mainPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
                tabbedPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

                ControlPanel controlPanel = new ControlPanel();

                tabbedPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
                controlPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 20, 20, 20));

                ECPanel ecPanel = new ECPanel();
                SMRPanel smrPanel = new SMRPanel();

                tabbedPane.addTab("Environnement Canada", null, ecPanel, "Convertir des données des stations d\'Environnement Canada");
                tabbedPane.addTab("Station Météo Routière", null, smrPanel, "Convertir des données des stations météos routières");

                mainPanel.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                mainPanel.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                window.add(mainPanel);

                new ControllerIRH(ecPanel, smrPanel, controlPanel);

                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The important bit is this object : `SMRPanel smrPanel = new SMRPanel();`

Inside this object I have a JButton `convertArchiveButton` that I add a ActionListener from a `Controller` class

```
public void addConvertArchiveButton(ActionListener ConvertArchiveButton) {
    convertArchiveButton.addActionListener(ConvertArchiveButton);
}
```

Here's the the implementation of the Listener in the Controller

```
private class ConvertArchiveButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
             converter.convert();
    }
}
```

`converter` is the class that does the lengthy operation

```
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int file = 0; file < listOfFiles.length; file++) {

     int progress = Math.round(file * 100 / listOfFiles.length);

     //tried a lot of things here...

    //...computing

}
```

I example tried to add some new `Runnable` with both `EventQueue` and `SwingUtilities` but didn't work. A `SwingWorker` class would be useful? Don't quite understand the use.

Basically, `int progress` would be passed to the `JProgressBar` in the `SMRPanel`.

EDIT WITH ControlAltDel answer :

Still doesn't work, `converter.readFile(file);` doesn't get called.

```
private class ConvertArchiveButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        System.out.println(listOfFiles.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            final File file = listOfFiles[i];
            final int idx = (i * 100) / listOfFiles.length;
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    converter.readFile(file);

                    System.out.println(idx);

                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            smrPanel.setProgressBarValue(idx);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            try {
                t.start();
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        converter.convert(year);

    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, you need your runnable to be executed in any thread but the EDT. EventQueue and SwingUtilities only dispatch to the EDT. Yes a SwingWorker will do a great job at this: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288303/best-example-for-programmatically-creating-splashscreen-with-text/16289376#16289376).

Comment: sorry, shoud be try try { t.start(); t.join(); } ...

Comment: I have modified my code... I made a mistake that could cause the file processing threads to complete and the adjustment of the ProcessBar to not take place in order. I have now fixed this

Comment: @ControlAltDel That was doing what you thought at first, but the update did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are running your loop in the EDT thread. Fix by running this in another thread, and then setting the updated progress value in the EDT when you finish processing a file

```
private class ConvertArchiveButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               for (int file = 0; file < listOfFiles.length; file++) {
                  final File f = listOfFiles[i];
                  final idx = file;
                  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    converter.convert(f);
                    swingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                      myProgressBar.setValue(idx);
                    });
                   t.start();
                   t.join();
                  });
                 }
             }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this but didn't work, I updated my question with the try at the end